# how to remap super keys?

Tags: x11, keyboard, xkb, xmodmap

I'm playing around with keyboard settings, and wanted to remap my windows keys to tab, for convenience. So I tried (133 is the left super key on my keyboard)

`xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Tab Super_L"`

but this didn't work, in that hitting the windows key still brings up the "windows" menu, and no tab is inserted. A few different variations on the same theme also didn't work, e.g. making the Tab happen on shift+super.

I'm using cinnamon (installed from a ppa on ubuntu 16.04) and lightdm, and I imagine that the windows/super key is being intercepted at a lower level, which xmodmap can't quite deal with...is there any way of achieving what I want? Answers not involving xmodmap are welcome!

(I'm far from an expert, so perhaps there's a very easy solution...)

Comment: Mixing modifiers and non-modifiers on the same key is tricky. You may need to run `add` or `remove` commands to set this up, or it may require going via XKB.

Comment: try something simpler like `xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = a b"` then check if key `133` writes `a` if pressed alone and `b` if pressed with `Shift`.  If it doesn't, it means key `133` doesn't understand `Shift` and it probably needs to be `TWO_LEVEL` instead of `ONE_LEVEL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Trying to understand what's happenning

If I type `xmodmap` without argument (to get modifier list), I get:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        ISO_Level5_Shift (0x69)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

The important part is for `mod4`. That's where `Super_L` is.

Now, I run : `xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Tab Super_L" && xmodmap | grep mod4`, and I get:

```
mod4        Tab (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
```

The `mod4` line changed and added `Tab`. That's why your key `133` still open the window menu.

By the way, I'm trying this on `I3WM` so the results can be a bit different.
For example, if I press the key `133` on a terminal or text editor, it both write a tab and becomes a modifier.

I also noticed I don't have a different behavior with `Shift` because the type of the key is `ONE_LEVEL`.

You can also run `xev | grep key` to see what happens with some key combinations.

## Solution

But `xmodmap` also tells you can't have more than 4 keys per modifier, so a solution (the only one that worked for me so far) is to sacrifice a key you don't use / don't have, make it become a `Super_L`.

If you use `QWERTY`, you can modify the layout located on `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` (it's usually another file of the same folder if you're using another layout), and write:

```
key.type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL";
key <MENU>{[Super_L]}; // ONE or TWO level, assuming MENU key isn't used
key <LWIN>{[ Tab, Super_L]}; // should be TWO_LEVEL
key.type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL";
```

instead of (probably line 14 of the file)

```
 key <LWIN>{[Super_L]};
```

Then, update your keyboard layout with `setxkbmap us && xmodmap | grep mod4`.
You will get something like:

```
mod4        Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0x87),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
```

If you still get `Tab`, you should probably sacrifice another key.
Note that `0x85` is the hexadecimal value of `133`, that mean this key will not be a direct `mod4` but it still can behave like window key if `Shift` is pressed.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer, I had totally given up on this! It'll take me a few days before I have a chance to try this out, so I'm going to mark the answer as accepted for now, and if I have any additional feedback I'll come back and comment here once I've played around with this a bit more.

Comment: ok, no problem. Feedback are welcome and can help me to understand if the behavior is the same on another desktop. Do as you want.